# How to access dynamic object keys

Tags: javascript, search

How can I loop trough array of objects and extract keys and values without knowing the names of the keys ?

sample json:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {Destination: "Usa"}
1: {Type: "commercial"}
2: {Transport: "plane"}
3: {price: "501-700"}
```

result wanted:
http://localhost/appname + ?destination=usa + &type=commercial+ etc...

Any general advice or pseudo code how to roughly code sidebar search by selecting options ? My plan is to :
1. add/remove selections to session storage array of objects by clicking the specific sidebar button;
2. create url from those selections.
3. use php, mysql to search database based on those selections in url. 
4. generate json page. 
5. update indexsearch.php data with javascript based on that json page.

Comment: Effort so far ? please post the code you've tried so far

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g27xc0pL/  so far it's this mess ;), i'm trying to follow my original plan, but stuck on generating url for php&mysql

Comment: @mario31 did you solve it? If so, accept one of the answers please

Comment: I don't have enough reputation yet to vote for :(

Comment: @mario31you can accept an answer by clicking the check mark under the vote count of an answer

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can use `map` to traverse through each of the objects in the array.

For each object in the array, I am also assuming there to be multiple key value pairs.
`Object.entries(obj)` returns an array of [key,value] pair tuples (arrays).

By joining these with '&' and joining the outer array of objs by '&' you get the desired result. You could use toLowerCase for removing any case sensitive issues

```js
let data = [{Destination: "Usa"}, {Type: "commercial"}, {Transport: "plane"}, {price: "501-700"}]
let result = 'http://localhost/appname?' + data.map(obj => Object.entries(obj).map(([key,value]) => key.toLowerCase()+"="+value).join('&')).join('&');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should provide the wanted result in a simple manner. Note, that the last character will be a `&`, but it's still a valid url. You can remove that character if you wish.

```js
const params = [
  {Destination: "Usa"},
  {Type: "commercial"},
  {Transport: "plane"},
  {price: "501-700"},
];

const url = params.reduce((res, param) => {
    Object.keys(param).forEach(key => {
        res += `${key}=${param[key]}&`
    })

 return res;
}, "http://localhost/appname?")
 
console.log(url);
// http://localhost/appname?Destination=Usa&Type=commercial&Transport=plane&price=501-700&
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var a = [
  {"Destination": "Usa"},
  {"Type": "commercial"},
  {"Transport": "plane"},
  {"price": "501-700"}
];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  var keys = Object.keys(a[i]);
  for (var k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
    console.log(a[i][keys[k]]);
  }
}
```

You can get array keys using `Object.keys()` and then loop through your array and then keys.

Then to create the full thing you're after:

```js
var a = [
  {"Destination": "Usa"},
  {"Type": "commercial"},
  {"Transport": "plane"},
  {"price": "501-700"}
];

var url = "https://localhost/appname";
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  var keys = Object.keys(a[i]);
  for (var k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      url += "?";
    } else {
      url += "&";
    }
    url += keys[k] + "=" + a[i][keys[k]];
  }
}
console.log(url);
```